# C# MySql if record exists update else insert?

Tags: c#, mysql

lets say i have a column uniqueID that had '1' in it.  What I want to do is only update called phonenumber total.  If it doesn't exist then insert. Is 'REPLACE into table' what I am looking for?

Comment: INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called an 'upsert' (UPdate/inSERT).

Examples at [How to write flexible INSERT and UPDATE statements in MySQL](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/02/21/flexible-insert-and-update-in-mysql/)

Comment: I like it but it will slow everything down a lot, is there a way to say if ROW exists blah or else?

Answer (score 0):

There is an SQL standard for this called "MERGE". Some recent version of Oracle and MSSQL2008+ support this. Not sure about MySQL